# How to Schedule Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I'm making google assistant which is able to play Prayer's Call, gets Prayer timings from the Prayer Api and able to set timing of Prayer as well, using Webhook of Nodejs. The problem is how can I schedule Prayer's Call timings to Dialogflow... like how can i invoke "Play Prayer's Call" intent via Nodejs in given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to call an intent on demand if you want to use google assistant, every message of google assistant, is triggered by an user message, to avoid spam.

Your best approach is to use [Notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) which are available for smartphones.

If you're using your custom chat, facebook messenger, telegram, you can indeed achieve that, by calling the intent using the Node.js Dialogflow library.

Comment: What about events which we used to define in intents. so, can we invoke events some how in a specific time? like you know whenever our action start, It automatically invoke welcome intent due to welcome's event.. so is their any way to invoke events from webhooks. Thank you

Comment: No, you can't. Actions are additional data you receive from the intent, so you execute a particular action on your backend.