# Trigger a custom alert phrase (Intent) with Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, webhooks, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'am new to Dialogflow, although it is easy to understand, I couldn't trigger an Intent with a custom event.

The task that I have to implement is that when an alert is detected in the backend node.js webhook (example: boss wants something done) the google assistant must alert the employee.

I tried with:

1. https://dialogflow.com/docs/events/custom-events
2. https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications

But I couldn't get it to work.

Am I on the right track? or are there other solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263634/how-to-schedule-dialogflow/53263699#53263699  Check this answer. It's not possible to do that.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande thank you for your response. As I mentioned in my question I already tested push notifications but i wasn't successful. But,since it might be the only way I will give it an other try.

Comment: Notifications have restrictions too, so most likely you won't be able to achieve that, since the anti spam policy of the Google Assistant is quite strict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push notifications works fine.I was able to send notifications in real time with some tolerable delai.

the following link has more details than the one on Google Actions website https://yoichiro.github.io/codelabs/actions-updates-and-notifications/?index=codelabs%2F#0